# UIButton randomly displaying graphic or title

Tags: ios, random, uibutton, assets

Two of my `UIButton`s are going nuts, somehow… During one session of the running app, every time I open the containing view controller, these two buttons randomly display either the png file or the title string set in the storyboard. See the screenshots attached.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Anyone here who ever had that issue?

Comment: Can You show your button code?

Comment: Weird. Do you have duplicate file names for the image used? One thing that comes to mind is that if you do have the same file name for images, it is non-deterministic which is chosen. Maybe there's a reference to an image that has been removed, so the button gets a `nil` image, and chooses to show the title instead?

Comment: I don't even have outlets to the buttons - so I'm not doing anything in code with them. And I don't have any duplicates in there. Only the extra pngs with the @2x suffix. So yes, weird. ;)

Comment: What happens if you remove titles? Do they appear completely blank?

Comment: Well... That seems to help. But that's weird. I was sure I did that the same way before.

Comment: Guntis, please add an answer so I can accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try cleaning your project Cmd+Shift+K then rebuild.

Comment: Nope, that did not change anything. Guntis comment did the trick.